# How to create a custom tabbar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

Guys I searched the internet and stackoverflow a lot, but did not find any solution for this.

I want to create a tabbar like this:

[image: tabbar that i want]

I just don't know how to create something like this. Could you please help me. I am just stuck with it for so long, i do not know how to do it.

```
 let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.appBlue(), size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)


    tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4
    tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2
```

This code does not work for me:

[image: tabbar that i have implemented]

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: added the image @Teetz

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a fast solution than I'd recommend you to use library like [this](https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController). But if you want fully flexible and controlled solution. Then, make it by your own through ViewController which will act as container for you tabBarView and content view controller. So, you get ContainerViewController with two childs: Currently selected ViewController and TabBarController (you own implementation of TabBarView). Whatever you will use both approaches will take time to understand how to use / implement it